# are the two codes same?

Tags: index, action

I'm starting to learn Magento 2 and I read some instructions to create Controller.

There are the index.php. on Magento 2 _ development cookbook and another on website.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
       protected $resultPageFactory;
public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
           \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
$resultPageFactory ){
$this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
           parent::__construct($context);
       }
       public function execute()
       {
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
           return $resultPage;
       }
```

and the another code that I read.

```
 class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();`
```

I saw that, two codes are show same layout page Magento. So what does the different between that ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General**

In Magento 2 all controller actions must return something, opposed to M1, where a controller action would just output something or did a redirect.
The result of the execute method from each controller is generated in `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::dispatch()` on line `$result = $actionInstance->execute();` and returned.

Depending on the type of the returned result a different action is performed.
The result can be and instance of :

- \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page - actually renders html
- \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect - redirects to an other
  page
- \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward - forwards to an other
  action (internal redirect)
- \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json - returns a json object.
- \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw - returns whatever you
  tell it to return (string).

**Specific**

`resultPageFactory` is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` and when calling create on that class it returns an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page` described above.
When this is used and the result is returned it means that your action will return HTML.
It has somehow a similar effect as `$this->loadLayout();` from Magento 1.
When you call create on the resultPageFactory object it actually loads the layout.

Comment: Thanks to Marius for providing good information about this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! :D